# Can I disable MyPy's "Cannot find implementation or library stub for module named..." error?

Tags: python, mypy

There are many threads regarding `Cannot find implementation or library stub for module named...` error, but there's no associated error code. I'd like to disable this completely. How might I go about doing that?

Comment: A short question does not mean a "bad" question; there is not much more information to be provided—I'd just like to disable an error message different from other error messages and thus not accommodating of the usual ways of disabling errors.

Comment: The problem is not that question is short. The problem is that this is clearly explained in [documentation](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/running_mypy.html) and thus has little value.

Comment: If you hover over the downvote arrow, you can see the reasons for downvoting: "This question does not show any research effort". Have you read the [documentation](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/running_mypy.html#missing-imports)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To disable the warning:

Pass the `--ignore-missing-imports` flag  on the CLI.

Or if using a config file:

For `mypy.ini` or `setup.cfg`

```
[mypy]
ignore_missing_imports = true
```

For `pyproject.toml`

```
[tool.mypy]
ignore_missing_imports = true
```

This will disable warning for all modules. You can set it on a per module basis, but you'll have to check the docs for examples on how to do that.